# IF ELSEIF fo array inside While loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, if-statement, while-loop

I've get the value inside literal tag in this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xml-to-html.xsl"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="Kategori"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="Kategori">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Gerak Kasar</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="Kategori">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Gerak Halus</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

using this code:

```
$x = 0;
$kategori = array();
while ($x < count($hasilcek->results->result)) {
$kategori[$x]= $hasilcek->results->result[$x]->binding->literal;
$x++; }
```

But when I try to get the result by IF ELSEIF inside WHILE using this code:

```
$x = $x-1;
while ($x > -1){
if ($kategori[$x] = 'Gerak Kasar') {echo "Gerak Kasar";}
elseif ($kategori[$x] = 'Gerak Halus') {echo "Gerak Halus";}
else {echo "tidak ada";}
$x--;}
```

exactly the result should be:

> Gerak
>   Kasar
>         
>       
>       
>         
>           Gerak
>   Halus

but why i get :

> Gerak KasarGerak Kasar

I think there is something wrong when I do IF selection for $kategori[] inside the WHILE. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of comparison operator your are using assignment operator.

```
if ($kategori[$x] = 'Gerak Kasar') {echo "Gerak Kasar";}
elseif ($kategori[$x] = 'Gerak Halus') {echo "Gerak Halus";}
```

So change it to

```
 if ($kategori[$x] == 'Gerak Kasar') {echo "Gerak Kasar";}
 elseif ($kategori[$x] == 'Gerak Halus') {echo "Gerak Halus";}
```

Because when `if ($kategori[$x] = 'Gerak Kasar')` is executed `$kategori[$x]`  become `Gerak Kasar` always. That is why you get the same result again.

Answer (score 0):

Selamat Pagi. :)

Try this :

```
$x = $x-1;
while ($x > -1){
if ($kategori[$x] == 'Gerak Kasar') {echo " Gerak Kasar ";}
elseif ($kategori[$x] == 'Gerak Halus') {echo " Gerak Halus ";}
else {echo "tidak ada";}
$x--;}
```

Comment: Pagi juga :D Wah bisa, jadi kalau string gitu harus double sama dengan ("==") ? Terima kasih

Comment: Ehm ehm Boleh minta poinnya? hehe